# MySQL Trigger updates all rows even if a distinct where clause is given

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

Refer to the following trigger,

```
create trigger trigger_update_rows after insert on transaction for each row

DECLARE tr_type VARCHAR(15);
DECLARE tr_op VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE tr_amt FLOAT(8,2);
DECLARE tr_qnt INTEGER;
DECLARE item_id INTEGER;
SET tr_type = NEW.TRANSACTION_TYPE;
SET tr_op = (SELECT TRANSACTION_TYPE_OPERATION FROM transaction_type WHERE 
TRANSACTION_TYPE_NAME=tr_type limit 1);
SET tr_amt = NEW.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT;
SET tr_qnt = NEW.QUANTITY;
SET item_id = NEW.ITEM_ID;
IF tr_op = 'ADD' THEN
update item set QUANTITY_AVAILABLE=QUANTITY_AVAILABLE-
tr_qnt,QUANTITY_SOLD=QUANTITY_SOLD+tr_qnt,AVAILABLE_GOODS_VALUE = 
AVAILABLE_GOODS_VALUE - tr_amt,SOLD_GOODS_VALUE=SOLD_GOODS_VALUE+tr_amt 
where ITEM_ID=item_id;
ELSEIF tr_op = 'SUBTRACT' THEN
update item set QUANTITY_AVAILABLE=QUANTITY_AVAILABLE+tr_qnt,QUANTITY_BOUGHT=QUANTITY_BOUGHT+tr_qnt,AVAILABLE_GOODS_VALUE=AVAILABLE_GOODS_VALUE+tr_amt,BOUGHT_GOODS_VALUE=BOUGHT_GOODS_VALUE+tr_amt where ITEM_ID=item_id;
END IF;
END
```

ITEM_ID is a primary key in the table item and the following is the transaction row inserted

```
insert into transaction(TRANSACTION_DATE,TRANSACTION_TYPE,ITEM_ID,QUANTITY,TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,ACCOUNT_ID,BUYER,SELLER) values ('2017-08-12','BUY',2,5,500.00,3,1,2);
```

What is making the above trigger update all rows in item instead following the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is:

```
where ITEM_ID = item_id;
```

You may think that one of the `item_id`s is somehow connected to the variable.  It is not.

Rename the variable to something like `v_item_id` and then use:

```
where item_id = v_item_id
```

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. Is this because, variables are not case-sensitive and it considers ITEM_ID and item_id as the same and for all rows item_id is equal to itself?

Comment: @TarunMohandas . . . It is because *identifiers* are case-insensitive and both references to `item_id` refer to the column.